# How can I enable hover opening in file explorer while holding a file in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

When I used to have a mac, there was a capability that while moving a file by dragging it in the file explorer, if you held a file over a folder for a while the folder will automatically open so you could then navigate into subfolders. Is there a setting (or installable mod) that allows me to do the same in windows 10? I found that there exists the same capability in the left navigation pane of file explorer, but I want this to be there in the main pane also.

Comment: Native Windows behavior for Windows Explorer does not open a file by hovering. It is different than MAC.

Comment: @John Yes, I know that is not part of the native behavior. I was looking for if there was some method to add it to Windows. Whether that be a mod or a setting.

Comment: There is no setting. I do not see a third party way to do this. Look at the Windows Tweak apps to see if they might. I do not find double click (after many decades) to be at all troublesome

Comment: The problem is I want it to open the folder while I am holding a file to move it in a subfolder. Since I am already holding the mouse button to hold the file, I can't double click. What are the Windows Tweak apps?

Comment: I will look around. Windows does not like to open a file in flight (confusion over the owning folder). I move, then open. It takes less time than to type the four word sentence.

Comment: @AlanAbraham a workaround : try https://github.com/indiff/qttabbar

Comment: @AlanAbraham If the left hand navigation pane does what you want, why do you want it to behave the same way in the main pane?

Comment: @NetServOps because I always have to start my navigation from desktop, documents etc. I can't start at a folder other than those unless I had already bookmarked it or it is in my quick access. Also some of my folders contain many folders. I find it easier to find the desired subfolder and less cluttered when I can see all the folders in the main pane rather than the navigation pane.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ko-sw.com/Products/Approach/features.aspx
program called ko-approach.  i have used this before.
caution, web site says not secure, but this did enable a dropdown menu on long right click of main folder, then you could navigate to subfolders just by hovering.
hope this is of some help.
i would like a more mainstream program that is currerntly maintea9ned (I don't think KO was updated for a  while) but take a look

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).